# accessing cookies from helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to be able to say `store[...]`  instead of `cookies[...]` in a controller (don't ask why - I also don't want to have to invoke 'permanent').  To that end I created the following in a helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper

      $cookies = 0

      class Store

        def self.[] (k)
          $cookies[k]
        end

        def self.[]= (k,v)
          $cookies.permanent[k] = v
        end  

      end    

      def store
        $cookies = cookies
        Store
      end
```

It works, but needless to say I'm not satisfied with it.  How can it be improved/shortened.  How could all references to "cookies" be put in the Store class itself.

Comment: It would be helpful for down voters to add a comment explaining themselves,

Comment: What exactly is insulting to someone about this query.  There's a lot of vagueness regarding variable scope in Ruby for someone coming from C++, etc.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I came up with an immediate improvment...

```
module ApplicationHelper

  class Store

    def initialize (cookies)
      @cookies = cookies
    end

    def [] (k)
      @cookies[k]
    end

    def []= (k,v)
      @cookies.permanent[k] = v
    end  

  end    

  def store 
     @store ||= Store.new(cookies)
  end
```